# Deploy node app into Google Cloud VM with firewalls

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, port, firewall

I have a node app running at port 3015

In my Google Cloud VM I have setup the Firewall port and linked this rule with my VM
But I still can't connect to port 3015 through my browser (in my localhost it works)
How can I solve this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show the following information in your question. 1) Show the firewall rule allowing port 3015. 2) Which OS and version? 3) Double check if you have a firewall running in your OS such as iptables, ufw, firewalld, etc. (which one depends on the OS) and show the configuration.

Comment: Use 'nmap' to check either the port 3015 is opened or not.